# Добавление компонентов на форму

Tags: java

Эта форма открывается по нажатию кнопки. Я пробую добавить в неё компонент `textfield`, но он не отображается. Пробовал уже для этой формы методы `revalidate()` и `repaint()`, но компонент все равно не отображается.

```
class Better implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

       form2.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       form2.setBounds(300,200,600,450);
       form2.setLayout(null);
       form2.getContentPane();
       form2.add(btn6);
       form2.add(btn7);
       form2.add(tf1);
       tf1.setLocation(200,150);
       form2.revalidate();
       form2.repaint();
       btn6.setSize(135,50);
       btn6.setLocation(450,360);
       btn7.setSize(134,50);
       btn7.setLocation(0,360);
       form1.setVisible(false);
       form2.setVisible(true);

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не задан размер для **tf1**, а вообще лучше пользоваться стандартным набором **Layout**'ов. Их комбинация для разных объектов формы уверен даст вам нужный результат. Размещение объектов с абсолютным позиционированием считается плохим тоном программирования за редким случаем. Что вы будете делать если вам перед первой кнопкой нужно будет добавить еще одну, или добавить объект который сместит вниз остальные элементы? Перебивать все константные значения?

Comment: Скажите, а вы сможете мне помочь написать интерфейс для БД пожалуйста?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как правильный). А так задавайте новый вопрос с конкретным примером где и что у вас не получается. Здесь много компетентных людей, готовых всем помочь, но делать что-то за вас никто не будет.